# Localization not working in presenting UIActivityViewController in swift 5

Tags: swift, xcode

My app supports both LTR and RTL. It works fine for all cases. If i change app language from app settings then in every screen language is updated and works fine.

When i press share button in app. Below code is executed.Here i want to show share picker in my app's selected language. But it doesn't show it in my app's language.

```
  let text = NSLocalizedString("I liked this view in app", comment: "")
    // set up activity view controller
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [text, urls], applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view // so that iPads won't crash
    
    // exclude some activity types from the list (optional)
    //    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [ UIActivity.ActivityType.airDrop, UIActivity.ActivityType.postToFacebook ]
    
    // present the view controller
    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)`
```

I have tried below code to update share view language change but it didn't work.

```
   if ( Language.currentLanguage == .arabic) {
        activityViewController.accessibilityLanguage = "ar-SA"
    }
    else{
        activityViewController.accessibilityLanguage = "en-US"

    }
```

I have also tried below code but it is also not working.

```
if ( Language.currentLanguage == .arabic) {
        activityViewController.view.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft

    }
    else{
        activityViewController.view.semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight

    }
```

Anyone could help me with this issue ?

PS
For share picker you can refer below screenshot :
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by share picker? would you like to share a screenshot?

Comment: Added screenshot for referenece

Comment: Have you found a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

A solution which worked for me. Go to your Info.plist and add Localized resources can be mixed with Boolean YES or NO to it, and check the result.

> As mentioned in Core Foundation Keys:
>
> CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations
>
> CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations (Boolean - iOS, macOS) specifies
> whether the bundle supports the retrieval of localized strings from
> frameworks. This key is used primarily by Foundation tools that link
> to other system frameworks and want to retrieve localized resources
> from those frameworks.

Comment: This is not working

Comment: @Beena Did you manage to solve this? If yes kindly let me know the solution